# Managing Sql Connections in C# Multithreading

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

I have written a c# multithread function that reads data from sqlserver and for each row of data starts a separate thread.In each thread I have codes that need to work with db.
this is what I do in each thread:

- Create a new sql connection
- Connect to it and open it
- Do work
- Close connection (while it is not necessary)

I should note that I use Using() command and I have read that this statement manages sql connection and closes it automatically after command is executed.

this function should be called periodically (say every 1 minute)
and this is the problem i get into:

after first call number of active sql connections increases to number of rows (Threads that created per each row).in the second call this number increases again. for example after 5 calls with 100 rows we have 500 active sql connections!
but I have read that connection pooling manages connections and uses created connections again.
what should i do to solve this problem?
did I miss any statement or is there something to do that I forgot?

Comment: Please provide some context to your question. What are you trying to achive? Is this a load testing application?

Comment: its a monitoring service and i insert devices that should be monitored to db and start a new thread for monitoring each device

Comment: Have a look if this has any relevance to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268982/net-sqlconnection-not-being-closed-even-when-within-a-using

Answer (score 0):

Using just is a try - finally, nothing more, it calls Dispose and that's all.

[in a "using" block is a SqlConnection closed on return or exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717789/in-a-using-block-is-a-sqlconnection-closed-on-return-or-exception)

Comment: ok if it calls dispose why connections stay open and do not close after dispose command?

Comment: It might remain opened because of the connection pool - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx .

You can limit the max number of the connections in the pool in the connection string: Max Pool Size=xxx .

Without a code snippet, I cannot help more.

Comment: Yes Its Because of the Connection Pool,How Can I limit The Time Connection Remains? Or is it a bad way to disable pooling?

Comment: In the connections string: Max Pool Size=xxx

Comment: what if I totally Disable It?

Comment: performance will go down, as you practically turn off the possibility of parallel access to the SQL server.